# Flutter with Firebase, Search by multiple queries

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a search feature that allows users to search by their username, email, designation or company. I intend to let users have the flexibility of typing any of those into the search bar and search for their target. However, what i am facing is that my code below only calls on the first function and displays results only for username (username is the first function here, can be interchanged with other functions and it will call according to that). my code is below and thanks for all the help in advance.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ib_club/services/database.dart';
import 'package:ib_club/widgets/widget.dart';

class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SearchScreen> createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> searchSnapshot;

  initiateUsernameSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = val;
      });
    });
  }

  initiateEmailSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByEmail(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = val;
      });
    });
  }

  initiateDesignationSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByDesignation(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = val;
      });
    });
  }

  initiateCompanySearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByCompany(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = val;
      });
    });
  }

  initiateSearch() {
    initiateUsernameSearch();
    initiateEmailSearch();
    initiateDesignationSearch();
    initiateCompanySearch();
  }

  // Create chatroom, send user to conversation screen, pushreplacement
  /*createChatroomAndStartConversation(String userUsername) {
    List<String> users = [
      userUsername,
    ];
    databaseMethods.createChatRoom();
  }*/

  Widget searchList() {
    return searchSnapshot != null
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SearchTile(
                userUsername: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["username"],
                userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"],
                userDesignation:
                    searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["designation"],
                userCompany: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["company"],
              );
            })
        : Container(
            /*child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                        const Color(0XffFBD24F))))*/
            );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: appBarMain(context),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                          const Color(0x36FFFFFF),
                          const Color(0x0FFFFFF)
                        ]),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: searchTextEditingController,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Search User",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white54),
                          border: InputBorder.none),
                    ),
                  )),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      initiateSearch();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                        height: 45,
                        width: 45,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                              const Color(0x36FFFFFF),
                              const Color(0x0FFFFFF)
                            ]),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45)),
                        child: Icon(Icons.search,
                            size: 30, color: const Color(0XffFBD24F))),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            searchList()
          ]),
        ));
  }
}

class SearchTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userUsername;
  final String userEmail;
  final String userDesignation;
  final String userCompany;

  SearchTile(
      {this.userUsername,
      this.userEmail,
      this.userDesignation,
      this.userCompany});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [const Color(0x36FFFFFF), const Color(0x0FFFFFF)]),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal()),
      child: Row(children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                userUsername,
                style: mediumWhiteTextStyle(),
              ),
              Text(
                userEmail,
                style: mediumWhiteTextStyle(),
              ),
              Text(
                userDesignation,
                style: mediumWhiteTextStyle(),
              ),
              Text(
                userCompany,
                style: mediumWhiteTextStyle(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0XffFBD24F),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
            child: Text(
              "Message",
              style: mediumTextStyle(),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not give a straight answer base on your code but I have a search concept, which I am hoping to help you in any way.

In my case, I always fetch all my item data from firebase and put it in "overallItems" (which is a List of Item Model). From there, I can now start to filter/search my list and return the result.

The concept I use is like this:

```
List<Item> filterItems() {
//first, I would want to have a temporary holder for a copy of my original items
final List<Item> itemHolder = List<Item>.from(overallItems);

//If user has title input on the search bar
if (titleKeyword.text != '') {
  //then this for loop will iterate to all my data
  for (final item in List<Item>.from(itemHolder)) {
    //will check each title from the list 
    if (!item.title.toLowerCase().contains(titleKeyword.text.toLowerCase())) {
      //elimate items that did not qualify
      itemHolder.remove(item);
    }
  }
}
//so after the first if, itemHolder will be left with the result....
//now, I would also like to search the seller name.
//then, I would just have to repeat the process above

//Searching for Seller Name
if (sellerKeyword.text != '') {
  for (final item in List<Item>.from(itemHolder)) {
    if (!item.sellerName
        .toLowerCase()
        .contains(sellerKeyword.text.toLowerCase())) {
      itemHolder.remove(item);
    }
  }
}

    //the itemHolder list will have the result
    return itemHolder;
  }
```

In the end, we will have the search result after the elimination process.

Comment: Hi, I found out that I am only able to present the Username as it is the first function in initiateSearch(). Is there any way I can have multiple function performed in gesture detector ontap()?

Comment: I think what you did is fine. It should've performed until the initiateCompanySearch(). Have you tried printing something inside your other search functions, just to make sure if it was really called?

Comment: yes, i did but the first function will always be called with no issues.