# Flutter, Calling 4 functions with onPressed()

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to call 4 functions when my FloatingActionButton is pressed. However, most of the time, the first function is being performed and I successfully retrieved the data from Firestore. Sometimes, upon multiple pressing of the button, other functions are being performed and i manage to retrieve data from Firestore. Is there any ways I can call all 4 functions?

```
onPressed: () {
                      initiateUsernameSearch();
                      initiateEmailSearch();
                      initiateDesignationSearch();
                      initiateCompanySearch();
                    }
```

Comment: The code you shared looks fine at first glance. More likely, the problem is not in the calling of these functions, but in what they actually do and how they depends on each other. Can you edit your question to show a [minimal-but-complete repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), essentially something that we can copy/paste to get the same problem you're having?

Comment: hey Frank, it relates to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72640203/flutter-with-firebase-search-by-multiple-queries/72640521#72640521

Comment: show loader so that it won't call again before finishing the queue. Once all call get finished hide the loader.

Comment: @msusare hi, how do i implement that?